"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом. как починить? Я ХЗ где у меня установленно
Короче, тут такая проблема - как только я пытаюсь использовать модуль "pyinstaller" у меня в терминале появляется это:

"pyinstaller" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

как починить, я хз что делать и где у меня скачаны библиотеки, у меня винда 11, я новичок поэтому не особо разбираюсь, прошу вашу помощь!

Если у тебя есть питон, попробуй написать в консоль 'pip', если покажет список команд это значит что у тебя он установлен. Напиши pip install pyinstaller и пользуйся, если напишет что pip не распознано как команда погугли как поставить pip, я сам мучился, пару раз переустановил python и вроде помогло.
